# Where should I find a Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6 operator's manual?

Tags: turboprop, turboshaft

I'm studying the PT6 in detail but the infos I get around the web are sometimes lacking in depth of informations.
I'm pretty much interested in the power curve vs RPM of this engine.
Where should I be able to find out the operators manual of the PT6?

Comment: the manufacturer?

Comment: There are multiple variants of the PT-6 are you asking about a specific one? Parameters may also change based on the airframe its installed on.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Pratt&Whitney

Comment: I meant ask the manuacturer

Comment: It probably is not meant to be available in the public domain for free. (Not to say that there aren't any bootleg copies out there.)  If you need it, you may well have to buy it. Start with P&W and see what they can tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Found it here

https://www.manualslib.com/manual/812510/Pratt-And-Whitney-Canada-Pt6a-Turboprop.html?page=1

First hit on google for "Pratt & Whitney Canada PT6 operator's manual"

Comment: That's a generic instructions manual. Not the Operator's manual. Thanks tho.